# JQuery array in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

This is a very general question. I am using MVC on the back in and JQuery for the front end. I have a select list of values for the user to choose from. I want the user to select the values on at a time by clicking the add button. But this truly does not save them this only stores them in an array. Then when the user clicks the save button i would pass the array to MVC controller method to do the database saves. My problem is that my array is not keeping values. i declare it global but if the page get refreshed or i call a method to filer the list by keyword value the array looses the contents that it had. How to i have an array in JQuery that keeps it value even after a post back?

Comment: what you have try so far?

Comment: Post your code to get a check

Comment: Let us know how you code to achieve this, i hope you missing form submit and keeping client variable. If you do like that it will get refresh always

Comment: Use HTML5 Browser Storage or Cookies

Answer (score 0):

Normally you shouldn't store unsaved data in javascript array and do postbacks. Obviously if the page is refreshed the data is being lost. So you should choose from two options:

1) You do it on the clientside. So you still have your javascript array, but you don't refresh your page until you are ready to save the data. In this case all the filtering and other stuff you mentioned should be done via AJAX calls from the clientside.

2) You do it on the serverside. So when you have the javascript array and you want to do a serverside postback with complete reload of the page, then you need to push your array to the serverside, but not save it into the database until you are ready. You can temporarily store it Session for example or other collections that persist data between different post backs.

This is high level explanation, I hope you can dig more.

EDIT:
James suggested another valid option of using browser storage of cookies. However storage is not supported in some older versions of different browsers. And I don't feel like this is the task you should use cookies for. It feels like work around to bad architecture.

Comment: thanks Deyneka, that was a good explanation and one i was looking for. I now have a better picture of what is happening.